# Sonarqube not showing any c# issues

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I installed Sonarqube in the same machine where I installed Jenkins. I'm starting a build everytime there is a push on gitlab, the build runs and sonar reports a correct build.

However I added code that is Noncompliant with the current profile (the default for c#).

**Sonar.project-propertries:**

```
sonar.projectKey=devkey:develop
sonar.projectName=FML
sonar.projectVersion=master

sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=cs
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

**build log:**

```
22:43:34 [ExampleJob] $ /opt/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778-linux/bin/sonar-scanner 
-e -Dsonar.host.url=http://........... ******** -
Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob
22:43:34 INFO: Option -e/--errors is no longer supported and will be ignored
22:43:34 INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778-
linux/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
22:43:34 INFO: Project root configuration file: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/sonar-project.properties
22:43:34 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
22:43:34 INFO: Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
22:43:34 INFO: Linux 3.13.0-119-generic amd64
22:43:35 INFO: User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
22:43:36 INFO: Load global settings
22:43:36 INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=134ms
22:43:36 INFO: User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
22:43:36 INFO: Load plugins index
22:43:36 INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=5ms
22:43:37 INFO: SonarQube server 6.4.0
22:43:37 INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
22:43:37 INFO: Process project properties
22:43:38 INFO: Load project repositories
22:43:38 INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=150ms
22:43:38 INFO: Execute project builders
22:43:38 INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=1ms
22:43:38 INFO: Load quality profiles
22:43:38 INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=29ms
22:43:38 INFO: Load active rules
22:43:39 INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=515ms
22:43:39 INFO: Load metrics repository
22:43:39 INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=112ms
22:43:39 INFO: Publish mode
22:43:39 INFO: Project key: devkey:develop
22:43:39 INFO: -------------  Scan FML
22:43:39 INFO: Load server rules
22:43:39 INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=101ms
22:43:39 INFO: Language is forced to cs
22:43:39 INFO: Initializer GenericCoverageSensor
22:43:39 INFO: Initializer GenericCoverageSensor (done) | time=0ms
22:43:39 INFO: Base dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob
22:43:39 INFO: Working dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/.scannerwork
22:43:39 INFO: Source paths: .
22:43:39 INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
22:43:39 INFO: Index files
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/Assets/TestScript.cs.meta' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/Assets/SceneViewWindow.cs.meta' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/GraphicsSettings.asset' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/Physics2DSettings.asset' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/ClusterInputManager.asset' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/AudioManager.asset' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/DynamicsManager.asset' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/QualitySettings.asset' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/NetworkManager.asset' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/TagManager.asset' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/InputManager.asset' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/UnityConnectSettings.asset' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/EditorSettings.asset' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/NavMeshAreas.asset' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/TimeManager.asset' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/ProjectSettings.asset' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/TestProj/ProjectSettings/ProjectVersion.txt' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/sonar-project.properties' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 WARN: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ExampleJob/README.md' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'
22:43:40 INFO: 2 files indexed
22:43:40 INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor C# [csharp]
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor C# [csharp] (done) | time=11ms
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=0ms
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php]
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php] (done) | time=8ms
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor C# Unit Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp]
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor C# Unit Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp] (done) | time=0ms
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp]
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp] (done) | time=0ms
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor C# Unit Test Results Import [csharp]
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor C# Unit Test Results Import [csharp] (done) | time=0ms
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=21ms
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
22:43:41 INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=1ms
22:43:42 INFO: SCM provider for this project is: git
22:43:42 INFO: 2 files to be analyzed
22:43:42 INFO: 2/2 files analyzed
22:43:42 INFO: Calculating CPD for 0 files
22:43:42 INFO: CPD calculation finished
22:43:42 INFO: Analysis report generated in 144ms, dir size=23 KB
22:43:42 INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 19ms, zip size=7 KB
22:43:43 INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 381ms
22:43:43 INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://.............
22:43:43 INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
22:43:43 INFO: More about the report processing at http://.............
22:43:43 INFO: Task total time: 5.951 s
22:43:43 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
22:43:43 INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
22:43:43 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
22:43:43 INFO: Total time: 8.665s
22:43:43 INFO: Final Memory: 46M/198M
22:43:43 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
22:43:44 Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using SonarQube Scanner for C#, but [SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild). Why? Because properties files are typically extremely difficult to configure accurately by hand for C# projects. A misconfiguration is probably what you're experiencing.

Using the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild, you'll bookend your build with scanner begin and end calls like so:

```
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"org.sonarqube:sonarqube-scanner-msbuild" /n:"Project Name" /v:"1.0"
MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
```

Using the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild, you don't need a properties file. Most of the values are read from your solution file, and the rest are passed on the initial commandline as shown above.

Comment: see my expansion @mFontoura.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that this won't work in a Linux VM?

Comment: And if I use the correct settings in the properties file?

Comment: The answer's still no. :-)